# Call logging with Dual SIM

Tags: android, calllog, dual-sim

I'm developing an application for Android 2.3.4.

This app gets all calls in call log and sends them to a server. The app works very well but now I have a problem. I have to add the Dual SIM option.

I've looked around and it seems that Android mixes the call log register of the both SIMs. Well, since I have to get only log of 1 SIM, how can I do that? Can Android do something like that (determining on call log which SIM got called) or do I have to change Android version?

Answer (score 2):

Any application built on Android will guarantee only for Single SIM mobiles. Because Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK. Device manufacturers who have created multi-SIM devices are doing so on their own. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer and see if they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the second SIM.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Way to find information about dual Sim in android API level 22 and above using [SubscriptionManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html), it provides a List SubscriptionInfo to the user which contain information about Multiple sims

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext());
        List<SubscriptionInfo> mSimInfo =  subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a new app which does the same

search for 2SIMCallLogger on Google Play/Market

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mashibo&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tYXNoaWJvIl0.

Comment: Posting a link to an app doesn't really help finding the programmatic solution.

Comment: Tried but this app also doesn't work as per expectation.