# Call logs for dual sim android device

Tags: android, calllog, dual-sim

I am using the below code to get the call log details which is working very fine for single SIM device, but the problem arises when it comes to the DUAL sim. I am trying to find work around for getting logs from dual sim device.

```
/**
     * Get All Call Logs details as JSON
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private void getInitialCallDetailsAsJSON() {
        // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa",
                Locale.getDefault());

        final Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;
        final Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(contacts, null,
                null, null, null);
        final int name = managedCursor
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
        final int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        final int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        final int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        final int durationOfCall = managedCursor
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        final JSONObject allDetailsJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        final JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

        if (managedCursor != null && managedCursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactName = managedCursor.getString(name);
                final String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                final String callTypeIndex = managedCursor.getString(type);
                final String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
                final String callDurationSeconds = managedCursor
                        .getString(durationOfCall);

                final int totalTime = Integer.parseInt(callDurationSeconds);
                int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(totalTime);
                long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(totalTime) - (day * 24);
                long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(totalTime)
                        - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(totalTime) * 60);
                long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(totalTime)
                        - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(totalTime) * 60);

                String callDurationFormatted = "";
                if (hours < 10) {
                    callDurationFormatted += "0" + hours + "h ";
                } else {
                    callDurationFormatted += hours + "h ";
                }

                if (minute < 10) {
                    callDurationFormatted += "0" + minute + "m ";
                } else {
                    callDurationFormatted += minute + "m ";
                }

                if (second < 10) {
                    callDurationFormatted += "0" + second + "s";
                } else {
                    callDurationFormatted += second + "s";
                }

                String callType = null;
                final int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeIndex);
                switch (dircode) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    callType = CallAnalyticsConstant.OUTGOING;
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    callType = CallAnalyticsConstant.INCOMING;
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    callType = CallAnalyticsConstant.MISSED;
                    break;
                }

                if (contactName == null || contactName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    contactName = "UNKNOWN";
                }
        }
        managedCursor.close();
    }
```

If anyone having any idea please kindly help me to get call related details for dual sim phones.

APP which is working fine for dual sim phone as  well - [CALL LOG MONITOR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softrelay.calllog)

Comment: what version OS(4.0 , 4.1 ...) of Single sim and what version of dual-sim have you tested ??

Comment: For single SIM Android version 4.1.2 - Sony Xperia P.

For dual SIM Android version 4.0.4 - Micromax A110 Canvas 2

Comment: [anything related to security ?](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/02/security-enhancements-in-jelly-bean.html)

Comment: I don't think its related to security as Call Log Monitor works perfect on both the devices. So its not about security. I think its about some trick or work around which we don't know but Call Log Monitor developer did that. So I am trying to find out that only.

Comment: [cant assure how much correct he is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12259378/1897935)

Comment: nothing directly related to your problem . [see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19474441/1897935) a UN-DOCUMENTED way to  programmatically call with 2 sims

Comment: I checked that answer but all most all apps in market are working with dual sim perfect so its not about SDK or anything. It must be some trick which we have to find.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50835/discussion-between-srinath-ganesh-and-scorpion)

Comment: Can anyone kindly help me for this!!!

Comment: [.apk](http://apkdownload4free.blogspot.in/2013/06/free-call-log-monitor-15-apk-on-blogger.html) & [decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/) .. hope this helps

Comment: @SrinathGanesh, Its very helpful and I got the code as well. But its having too much extra code and its clumsy as well so that it will take a lot time to clean it up. But the main thing which I was finding is i think same as my code. Let see. But thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Search tells me that **android.provider.CallLog** has been used in classes **com.softrelay.calllog.core.DbMonitor** AND **com.softrelay.calllog.core.LogManager**

Comment: In **com.softrelay.calllog.core.LogManager** , line number **709** , you have `cursor = CallLogApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://logs/historys"), as, s, null, "date DESC")` .. this looks a good place to check

Comment: you got ant thing new ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use "sub_id" constant value to get information about sim card.

Full path to this value CallLog.Calls.SUB_ID = "sub_id", but is not available for public, so just hardcode in API before 21. For >=21 you can use PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME.

```
     /**
     * The subscription ID used to place this call.  This is no longer used and has been
     * replaced with PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME/PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID.
     * For ContactsProvider internal use only.
     * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
     *
     * @Deprecated
     * @hide
     */
    public static final String SUB_ID = "sub_id";
```

Have a fun :)

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more? It will be very appreciated if there is a full example or a code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method which give you the All Call Logs Detail...

```
 private void getCallDetails() {

         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
         int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
         int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
         int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
         int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
         sb.append( "Call Details :");
         while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
                 String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
                 String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
                 String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
                 Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                 String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
                 String dir = null;
                 int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
                     switch( dircode ) {
                     case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                     dir = "OUTGOING";
                     break;

                     case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                     dir = "INCOMING";
                     break;

                     case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                     dir = "MISSED";
                     break;
                     }
                 sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
                 sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
         }
         managedCursor.close();
         System.out.println(sb.toString());
         }
```

And Also don't forgot to add these permissions in Manifest.Xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

Comment: can u highlight the differences ?? (OPs code works in single sim and not in dual sim)

Comment: @Android Guru, Sorry but its not working. There is only 1 difference in your code and my code that is you have used managedQuery and I have use query. Thanks for your time but unfortunately its not working and also one more thing is that managedQuery is deprecated and not advised to use. Once again thanks, I have to dig into details to find the answer

Comment: @Scorpion This code is working for me..I am using Micro-max Canvas HD for testing..which device you are using for testing?

Comment: I am having Micromax A110 and its not working in that, also I tested it on Moto G as well but not working.

Comment: @Scorpion come on android coders room we will discuss there

Comment: @Scorpion have u got the solution??