# How to get call logs of only one sim if you have 2 sim in a phone?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I want to develop an app which can access the call logs of the user, but only access the log of a particular sim if the user have 2 sim in their phone.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32444119/17994624):

> You can use "sub_id" constant value to get information about sim card.

> Full path to this value CallLog.Calls.SUB_ID = "sub_id", but is not available for public, so just hardcode in API before 21. For >=21 you can use PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME.

`PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME` is officially documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME), along with the rest of the documentation on accessing call logs.